# Is it possible to "dumb down" Linux to send ethernet datagrams over Lightning/30-pin dock connector?

Tags: networking, networkmanager, ethernet, iphone

I am wanting to 'reverse' tether my Linux desktop with an iPhone (Linux acting as server/router and iPhone is its client). Thanks to Apple, it is a lot of PITA to do anything hacky with their mobile devices. I have came across various webpages already and the best thing I saw was it requires jailbreak to accomplish. On the other hand there are lots of RJ-45 to Lightning adapters available in online market-places and according to online guides, it is simply plug-n-play to use ethernet using those adapters. Using one of those, I can possibly reverse tether the iPhone by

```
Linux#-EthernetOverTwistedPairs-#Adapter-=iPhone 
# : RJ 45
= : Lightning
```

**So, is it possible to for Linux to simply send the datagrams (correct me if the terminology is wrong) directly over a 'USB A to Lightning' cable (forgetting anything it know about iPhone), thus skip the need of intermidiate adapter to map RJ-45 signals to Lightning ? Also for 30-pin dock connector (the older connector of Apple devices)**

Note: *NetworkManager* marks the connected iPhone as an ethernet interface. It uses `ipeth` (iPhone Ethernet) driver to do so, which is intended for tethered (iPhone to Linux) mobile data sharing. Setting up a shared ethernet conection in *NetworkManger* is possible but no network can be seen/used from the iPhone. So that's why the 'dumbing down' part comes, to not use the `ipeth` thingy.

Comment: What does it have to do with Linux anyway? If what you are trying to do is to share the network/Internet access of the desktop with your iPhone, the point is to make your iPhone make use of another interface (instead of the WiFi or Cellular one). (But certainly, *once* you have achieved that, you'll need to configure Linux to do IP forwarding and perhaps NAT as well.)

Comment: As I have stated iPhone does accept internet access over Lightning. The question is how to make Linux send them **properly**? @TomYan

Comment: While I'm not exactly familiar with the Apple ecosystem, I don't think an "RJ-45 to Lightning adapter" is what you think it is, i.e. some "passive" adapter that works like an HDMI to DVI one or USB-C to DP one. Rather it's a proper USB NIC just like one you can plug into a PC or to an Android phone (except it is physically implemented with a Lightning connector, which can carry USB signal anyway). See [this](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK0W2AM/A/lightning-to-usb-3-camera-adapter) as a reference btw.

Comment: FYI, the reason that networking works over "a USB to lightning cable" with USB tethering is that, your iPhone works as a USB device in such case (instead of a USB host in the case with the "RJ-45 to Lightning" adapter), i.e. a NIC for your desktop. And the problem you have is that, your iPhone works as a router automatically in such case (like some PC or so configured to work as a "hotspot"), and it takes jailbreaking for you to configure it to work otherwise, which is why it has nothing to do with your desktop / Linux (you can totally configure it not to use the phone as its default gateway).